# wordpress autoloader in functions file

Tags: php, wordpress, autoloader

I've been researching autoloaders in wordpress and have been using them in custom plugins with no issues - however I wanted to try using it in a functions file inside a custom theme and it's not working random classes are being auto loaded. My question is can I use a custom autoloader in the functions.php file

some code is below:

```
spl_autoload_register('my_class_file_autoloader');

function my_class_file_autoloader($class_name) {

if(0 !== strpos($class_name, 'Mt')) {
    return;
}

$class_name = strtolower($class_name);
require get_template_directory() . '/classes/' . $class_name . '.php';}
```

classes are inside a classes folder, filenames are mt_class.php and the class name is Mt_Class

Any help is appreciated

Comment: what do you mean by "random classes being autoloaded"?

Comment: I mean that the classes I was expecting to be loaded were not. It was loading in classes that were not located within the classes folder.

Comment: Can you show me an example of where and how you instantiate an object?

Comment: Here is a pasted example - currently the custom project post type is being required at the top of the custom post types class. I then create a private variable and then in the constructor assign the variable to the custom post type class.
private $project;
    public function __construct() {

        //initialise the custom post type variables as the custom post type classes
        //$this->custom_post_type = new Custom_Post_Type_Class
        $this->project = new Mt_Project_Post_Type();
    }